# The dependency WebActivatorEx could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net5

I am building a small web api and i wish to use Swagger ui to test it.
However, when i install it, i get the following errors:

1. DNX 4.5.1 error NU1001, in project.json: The dependency WebActivatorEx  could not be resolved.
2. DNX Core 5.0 error NU1002, in project.json: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client     4.0.20710 in project DiveApi does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

My dependencies look as follows : 
[image: RefernceList]

I am using ASP.NET 5 Web API.

So far the suggestions i have found have not solved my problem and have no clue what to do from here. Hope I have supplied sufficient info, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer version of `Swashbuckle`: [6.0.0-rc1-final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/6.0.0-rc1-final). It is still a pre release so, in NuGet manager you have to enable pre release versions.

Comment: That package is delisted. What should be used now?